# Using a type of a parameterized data type in a Haskell function

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Let's say I have some algebraic data type in Haskell:

```
data Foo a = ...
```

I'd like to have a function that could "extract" this type `a` and do something with it, assuming it satisfies certain conditions. Specifically, I need something like:

```
fun :: Bounded a => Foo a -> a
```

with intended usage as follows:

```
fun foo = maxBound :: a
```

Of course this notation is incorrect in Haskell, but I think my intentions are clear. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need anything, it just works.

```
fun :: Bounded a => Foo a -> a
fun _ = maxBound
```

The compiler knows that the result of `fun` would be an `a` and therefore will call the correct `maxBound`.